# Trying to locate Codeigniter function executed in the view file

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to find where below query is coming from. Below is executed in view file which is resource_update.php but I cannot find add_resource function from resource controller...

Is there a reason why?

```
$this->resources->add_resource($desc_arr, $desc_limit, $new_clients);
```

Comment: If this is a query, try to look on model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if "resources" is actually a library or a model. I don't think we ever need to call another controller from a view (which is again loaded by a controller).

i.e., How is resources loaded?

```
$this->load->library('resources');
```

or

```
$this->load->model('resources');
```

Other than lack of sleep, I see no reason why you should not find the function that way. :)

If its really bothering you - try Changing your IDE to PhpDesigner, Netbeans etc. They have a cool way of finding the function definition and code hinting.

Cheers!